# How to handle System.OutOfMemoryException when using protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net in a c# application to load and save my program's 'project files'. At save time, the program creates a ProjectData object and adds many different objects to it - see general principle below.

```
static ProjectData packProjectData()
{
    ProjectData projectData = new ProjectData();

    projectData.projectName = ProjectHandler.projectName;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Module> kvp in DataHandler.modulesDict)
    {
        projectData.modules.Add(serializeModule(kvp.Value));
    }

    return projectData;
} 

[ProtoContract]
public class ProjectData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<SEModule> modules = new List<SEModule>();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string projectName = "";
}
```

Once this is created, it's zipped and save to the disk. The problem I am having is that when the number of modules gets very big (40,000+) System.OutOfMemoryException is being reported during the packProjectData function.

I've seen questions like this asked already, but these do not contain a clear answer to address the problem. If anyone can give me either a specific solution, or a general principle to follow that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not all that likely to be a protobuf-specific problem.  Your program ought to consume a lot of address space with so many "modules", not leaving enough room for protobuf to get its job done.  It might be teetering on the edge and any substantial operation can trip OOM.  "Too much data" has not been a practical problem for over a decade.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What sort of size are we talking about here? Most likely this is due to buffering required for the length prefix - something that v3 will address, but for now - if the file is huge, a pragmatic workaround might be:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ProjectData
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Grouped)]
    public List<SEModule> modules = new List<SEModule>();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string projectName = "";
}
```

This changes the internal encoding format of the `SEModule` items so that no length-prefix is required. This same approach may also be useful for some elements inside `SEModule`, but I can't see that to comment.

Note that this changes the data layout, so should be considered a breaking change.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll try that. When you say a breaking change - will that prevent files saved before the DataFormat.Grouped attribute being added from being desrialized?

Comment: @DerekNash I try to use the "conservative in what you send, liberal in what you accept" approach; it *might* still deserialize - try it and see :)